# How to randomly keep values to a specific numbers and replacing rest with no data in 2d numpy array without changing anything others

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy, arcpy

I am new in scientific computing.
I have a 2D numpy array(say, A) with shape as `(11153L, 4218L)`, datatype is `dtype('uint8')` .Now, I want to keep data at some(say, 10000) random positions (row,col) and fill the rest with `no-data-value`- How can I do this?

Here `no-data-value` is got from another environmental variable e.g.`my_raster_nodata_values = dsc.noDataValue`

Comment: Rollback the Update section as the issue has been resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`np.random.choice`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) with the optional arg `replace` set as `False` to select unique indices for the total size of that array and set those in it as `no_data_value`. Thus, an implementation would be -

```
a.ravel()[np.random.choice(a.size,a.size-10000,replace=0)] = no_data_value
```

Alternatively, we can use [`np.put`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.put.html) as to make it more intuitive, like so -

```
np.put(a, np.random.choice(a.size,a.size-10000,replace=0), no_data_value)
```

A sample run should make it easier to understand -

```
In [94]: a     # Input array
Out[94]: 
array([[163,  80, 142, 169, 214],
       [  7,  59, 102, 104, 234],
       [ 44, 143,   7,  30, 232],
       [ 71,  15,  64,  42, 141]])

In [95]: no_data_value = 0  # No value specifier

In [98]: N = 10 # Number of elems to keep

In [99]: a.ravel()[np.random.choice(a.size,a.size-N,replace=0)] = no_data_value

In [100]: a
Out[100]: 
array([[  0,   0, 142,   0,   0],
       [  7,   0,   0, 104, 234],
       [  0,   0,   7,  30, 232],
       [ 71,   0,  64,   0, 141]])
```

---

If you already have one or more elements in the input array that are equal to `no_data_value`, we might want to offset the number of elements to be set based on that count. So, for such a case, we would have a modified version, like so -

```
S = a.size - N - (a == no_data_value).sum()
idx = np.random.choice(np.flatnonzero(a!=no_data_value),S,replace=0)
a.ravel()[idx] = no_data_value
```

Sample run -

```
In [65]: a
Out[65]: 
array([[240,  30,  61,  38, 145],
       [ 91,  65, 108, 154, 118],
       [155, 198,  65,  65, 189],
       [248, 140, 154, 186, 186]])

In [66]: no_data_value = 65  # No value specifier

In [67]: N = 10 # Number of elems to keep

In [68]: S = a.size - N - (a == no_data_value).sum()

In [69]: idx = np.random.choice(np.flatnonzero(a!=no_data_value),S,replace=0)

In [70]: a.ravel()[idx] = no_data_value

In [71]: a
Out[71]: 
array([[240,  30,  61,  38,  65],
       [ 65,  65, 108,  65,  65],
       [ 65, 198,  65,  65,  65],
       [248, 140, 154, 186,  65]])
```

Comment: well enough! but is there a way without transforming the original array- i mean performance issue since i will have to work with almost 10000 rasters. Is `put`  faster than `ravel`?

Comment: @SIslam Not sure what you mean by `transforming the original array`? If by that, you mean putting  `no_data_value` in the original array, I guess that's what the question is about. If not, could you elaborate?

Comment: @SIslam If you are referring to `a.ravel()`, that `ravel()` is merely a view into  the array and as such there's no transformation there.

Comment: May be my mis-understanding. I mean i just read that `ravel` returns a flattened array so I think it transforms the original array then sets the nodatavalue.

Comment: @SIslam That's merely a flattened view into the array, no transformation or copying there.

Comment: last help! now how can i count the number of the non- nodatavalue- just a cross check..

Comment: @SIslam `(a != no_data_value).sum()`?

Comment: Ah cross-check gives error. could you please guide..I wanted to post it yesterday night but it was too late night here. I edited the question.

Comment: Why this happens when i used `eq[eq!=0] = raster_nodata_values` and tested `np.unique(eq)` what gives `array([ 0, 15], dtype=uint8)`

Comment: @SIslam Not sure what you mean there. Maybe edit the question to elaborate with sample?

Comment: I mean why I have to exclude `(a == no_data_value)` explicitly while there is only two types `array([ 0, 15], dtype=uint8)` to get the value of `S`. Care I filtered only to two values `eq[eq!=0] = raster_nodata_values`. Here `no_data_value = raster_nodata_values = 15`

Comment: @SIslam Do you mean `a` won't have any element that is equal to `no_data_value`?